# Grabbing twitter feed in bootstrap slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can currently load only one tweet from the stream into the slideshow. I think its just a matter of placement of the `<div id="feed">` in the right place, but I'm missing something.

My HTML has it placed in one of the `carousel-content` divs, but I think it needs to just be one of the content divs with feed:

```
    <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                            <div id="feed">
                                <ul class="tweets">
                                    <li class="tweet"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                             <h3>#1</h3>

                            <p>This is a twitter bootstrap carousel that only uses text. There are no images in the carousel slides.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                             <h3>#2</h3>

                            <p>This is a twitter bootstrap carousel that only uses text. There are no images in the carousel slides.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                             <h3>#3</h3> 
                            <p>This is a twitter bootstrap carousel that only uses text. There are no images in the carousel slides.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

The Javascript is in the fiddle below.

The currently working version: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/gXN2u/315/)

Comment: Essentially you need to initialize the carousel after creating the tweets, and have each `<li class="tweet item">` created, so it knows what to slide through.

Comment: Do you mean having the carousel jquery come after the twitter jquery? And change the class of the `tweets`?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia, can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I wasn't able to do it in the JSFiddle.  You're essentially loading 10 tweets inside one slide.  You need each tweet to act as a slide, so, by adding "item" to the tweet class, you can have the tweets container be the carousel.

Comment: Yes, all the tweets are ending up in the first slide (though only one tweet is available in the first slide). I added `item` to the tweet class on line 158 of the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/gXN2u/317/, but its still not producing the right result of showing each tweet in a slide. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was a bit simpler. Grab the feed, then create the inner elements to put the tweets into:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parser" style="display: none"></div>

               <div class="container">

                 <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="row slides">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>

            </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var Twitter ={};

 Twitter.callback = function(jsonP){
             //console.log("json", jsonP);
             var parser = $(".parser"),
             container = $(".carousel-inner"),
             tweets,
             i,
             createItem = function(item,index){

               var div = $('<div class="item'+((index === 0)?' active':'') +'"></div>'),
               divInner = $('<div class="carousel-content"></div>');
               console.log('<div class="item'+((index === 0)?' active':'') +'"></div>');
               div.append(divInner.append($(item).children()));

               div.append($(item).children());

               return div;
           };

           parser.html(jsonP.body);



           tweets = $('.h-feed').children('li');

           for(i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++){                   
            container.append(createItem(tweets[i],i));
        }


    }

    window.addEventListener("load" , function(){
     var jp = document.createElement("script");
     jp.src = "https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/506829210191552512?&lang=en&callback=Twitter.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd=0.3450709420721978";
     var hd = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
     hd.appendChild(jp);

 });
```